pyqt5 change QMessageBox when using multiprocessing (Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread)?
Here is an example, based on the example here Terminate a long-running Python command within a PyQt application - but with QMessageBox:
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QDialog,
                             QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QDialogButtonBox, QMessageBox)

from multiprocessing import Pool

def mp_long_task():
    for x in range(2):
        print('long task:', x)
        time.sleep(1)
    return 'finished'


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, pool):
        super().__init__()
        button = QPushButton("Start", self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.long_task)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.show()
        self.pool = pool

    def long_task(self):
        msgBox = QMessageBox( QMessageBox.Information, "Long task", "long task...", QMessageBox.Cancel, parent=None )
        orig_ipmsize = msgBox.iconPixmap().size()
        orig_ipm = msgBox.iconPixmap()
        msgBox.setIcon( QMessageBox.NoIcon )
        def callback(msg):
            #print(msg)
            msgBox.setText(msg)
            msgBox.setIconPixmap(orig_ipm) # QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
        self.pool.apply_async(mp_long_task, callback=callback)
        if msgBox.exec_() == QMessageBox.Cancel:
            pool.terminate()
            msgBox.done(0)
            print('terminated')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow(pool)
    app.exec_()

The mp_long_task is started when you click the Start button; terminating the mp_long_task with Cancel button actually works fine - but if you wait for the mp_long_task to complete on its own, then callback runs, and in it:

The msgBox.setText(msg), if its on its own (that is, the msgBox.setIconPixmap... line is commented), applies the text and the QMessageBox stays on screen - which is what I expect the behavior to be
If the msgBox.setIconPixmap(orig_ipm) is uncommented and it runs, then a sort of a segfault occurs, and the whole app crashes with:

QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
QCoreApplication::postEvent: Unexpected null receiver

How should I set up this code so it works: that is, when the multiprocessing .apply_async called task completes on its own, how can I both change the text and change the icon pixmap, keeping the QMessageBox, without the application crashing?

OK, I think I got this going, thanks to:

PyQt5: single QProgressBar with multiprocessing gets stuck
Python - PyQt Signals - Emit and send argument to different class

It seems, the main thing is, to set up the code so when the callback runs (when the long task finishes on its own), we just emit a signal with the right arguments - then have a class method handle the signal (and to have that work, also msgBox needs to become a class property, i.e. self.msgBox).
And here is the corrected code - it now also allows for multiple "cancel" (premature termination), then restart of the long task (this requires instantiation of pool whenever the long task is started); and of course, it long task completes on its own, then both text and icon pixmap are changes, and there is no crash.
import sys
import time
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QDialog,
                             QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QDialogButtonBox, QMessageBox)
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot
import PyQt5.QtGui

from multiprocessing import Pool

def mp_long_task():
    for x in range(2):
        print('long task:', x)
        time.sleep(1)
    return 'finished'


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, pool):
        super().__init__()
        button = QPushButton("Start", self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.long_task)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.show()
        self.pool = pool
        self.msgBox = None

    long_task_done = pyqtSignal(str, PyQt5.QtGui.QPixmap)
    @pyqtSlot(str, PyQt5.QtGui.QPixmap)
    def handle_long_task_done(self, msg, orig_ipm):
        self.msgBox.setText(msg)
        self.msgBox.setIconPixmap(orig_ipm) # QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread

    def long_task(self):
        self.pool = Pool()
        self.msgBox = QMessageBox( QMessageBox.Information, "Long task", "long task...", QMessageBox.Cancel, parent=None )
        orig_ipmsize = self.msgBox.iconPixmap().size()
        orig_ipm = self.msgBox.iconPixmap()
        print(orig_ipm)
        self.msgBox.setIcon( QMessageBox.NoIcon )
        self.long_task_done.connect(self.handle_long_task_done)
        def callback(msg):
            #print(msg)
            self.long_task_done.emit(msg, orig_ipm)
        self.pool.apply_async(mp_long_task, callback=callback)
        if self.msgBox.exec_() == QMessageBox.Cancel:
            self.pool.terminate()
            self.msgBox.done(0)
            print('terminated')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = None #pool = Pool()
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow(pool)
    app.exec_()

